# Why does the emoji ☘️ sometimes look like ☘?

Tags: python, unicode

I tried to identify an emoji in a text file. It looks like this: ☘️.
But when I tried parsing the file for ☘️, I couldn't find it. As it turns out, I can only identify this emoji when I am instead looking for ☘.

In case your browser renders them differently, here is a screen-shot of the two emojis side by side:
[image]

How can I automatically convert the first emoji (☘️) into the second (☘)? I am not sure if or how that would possible since they should already be the same.

Comment: They look absolutely identical to me. https://stack.imgur.com/Y2LrH.jpg

Comment: This is how it looks to me: https://imgur.com/a/SjiW9Sf Could you please open the therad again?

Comment: Seems like you're dealing with [*variation selector*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_Selectors_\(Unicode_block\)) issues: Unicode has 16 variation selectors, VS15 and VS16 are used to request respectively a text (black&white) emoji or a color emoji, instead of whatever the default is (which might be either). Your first version of the shamrock is followed by a VS16, the second is followed by nothing. So the answer would be to check for and strip out variation selectors. Simply, first one is "shamrock (color)" while the second is "shamrock". On your system the default is text.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question anyway. Maybe ask at [su] instead?

Comment: They look different in Firefox, and they are different sequences; the first one is the "emoji version" of the \u2618 codepoint. Indeed, the emoji version is codified by the same codepoint followed by a \ufe0f "emoji variation selector" codepoint. This is a valid question and should be reopened.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, ...but is it a valid question _about writing software_? Why here, and not [Super User](https://superuser.com/)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sure, why not? If they're doing the search programmatically and every string they tried worked but this one failed for instance. The post is tagged `python` after all.

Comment: @Masklinn, ...if they included a [mre] with Python code sufficient to reproduce the problem when run without changes, I'd fully agree that this was unambiguously topical. As it is, though, I don't see why someone couldn't encounter the same problem in a non-development context -- pressing ctrl+f in a browser and pasting one of the two codepoints into the search box while the other codepoint is represented in the page, f/e -- and our scope requires questions to be _unique to_ software development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So much information in the comments, yet nobody's written it all into an answer.

Your first emoji is actually a combination of two different Unicode codepoints, [U+2618 SHAMROCK](https://charbase.com/2618-unicode-shamrock) and [U+FE0F VARIATION SELECTOR-16](https://codepoints.net/U+FE0F?lang=en).  The second acts as a modifier to the first, converting it to a color rendering if all the parts of your display chain support it.  Some don't, my Chrome browser on Windows shows the two emoji identically.

The second emoji is just the single codepoint U+2618 without a modifier.

To convert all occurrences of the first to the second with Python is trivial:

```
s = s.replace('\u2618\ufe0f', '\u2618')
```